# sed - change input casing to ALLCAPS_Camel (SCOTT_Dummy)

Tags: sed

I am having difficulty taking the input from a user and formatting in such a way that it's standardized for my script.

I would like to take whatever the user gives me and then uppercase everything before the _ and only the first letter after the _

ie:

```
Enter username: SCOTT_Dummy
```

The user could also give me input:

```
scott_dummy
SCOTT_DUMMY
```

And I'd like sed to format it in the way that my script needs it to be:

```
SCOTT_Dummy
```

Comment: There is no *portable* way to do this easily in `sed`. Would you accept a solution in Perl or Awk? Or can you specify a platfor or `sed` version to target? Anyway, what have you tried? You are expected to show some effort (if only to tell us you have googled before asking).

Comment: I can take it in any form that Linux will be able to execute. Awk is fine.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/([^_]*_.)(.*)/\U\1\L\2/' file
```

Replace all characters that are not an `_` followed by an `_` followed by one additional character with their uppercase equivalent and all characters thereafter by their lowercase equivalent.

N.B. This will not change anything if the string does not contain an `_`. To uppercase all leading characters regardless of an `_`, use:

```
sed -E 's/([^_]*_?.)(.*)/\U\1\L\2/' file
```

Another way:

```
LU=$(printf "%s" {a..z} / {A..Z}) UL=$(printf "%s" {A..Z} / {a..z})
sed '/_./{y/'$LU'/;s//&\n/;h;y/'$UL'/;H;g;s/\n.*\n//}' file
```

To emulate the optional `_` solution, use:

```
L=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz U=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
sed 'y/'$L'/'$U'/;/_./{s//&\n/;h;y/'$U'/'$L'/;H;g;s/\n.*\n//}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this in POSIX `sed` is complex and ugly; you'd basically have to split out the part you want to normalize, then do case conversion with `y/abc...xyz/ABC...XYZ` and glue back the parts together.

Some `sed` versions have a non-standard extension from Perl (which was borrowed in turn from `vi`) but of course then you might as well use Perl, which is not POSIX at all but reasonably standard in actual practice.

```
perl -pe 's/([^_]+)_([^_])([^_]*)/\U\1\E_\u\2\L\3/'
```

This won't do anything to text after the second underscore on a line, or to text which doesn't contain an underscore.

See [the `perlre` manual page](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for an explanation of the regex parts. The `-p` option causes Perl to behave pretty much like `sed` and the `s/.../.../` is of course identical (though Perl also has many other juicy additions and extensions around it).